# Find all the keys of repeated element in bimap

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bimap

I want to access all the keys of a repeated element in `bimap`. I have some example code below

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/set_of.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/multiset_of.hpp>

namespace bimaps = boost::bimaps;
typedef boost::bimap<bimaps::set_of<unsigned long int>,
        bimaps::multiset_of<unsigned long int > > bimap_reference;
typedef bimap_reference::value_type position;
bimap_reference numbers;

int main()
{
    numbers.insert(position(123456, 100000));
    numbers.insert(position(234567, 80000));
    numbers.insert(position(345678, 100000));
    numbers.insert(position(456789, 80000));


    auto it = numbers.right.find(100000);
    std::cout<<"numbers:"<<it->first<<"<->"<<it->second<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I have repeated elements on right side. The above code give me the first key of the element `100000`, i,e `123456 <--> 100000`. But I have one more entry of the element `100000`, how to access all the keys of the repeated element (the element may be present multiple times with unique key on left side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [multiset::equal_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/equal_range) on the right hand side.

In this way you get an iterator range from the first occurrence to the last which you need to then iterate.

```
using ritr = bimap_reference::right_const_iterator;

std::pair<ritr, ritr> range = numbers.right.equal_range(100000);

for (auto itr = range.first; itr != range.second; ++itr)
{
        ...
}
```

---

*Edit:*

The `using ritr` statement makes `ritr` an alias for the actual type. It's equivalent to a `typedef` which you use higher up.

The alias simply makes the next line easier to read than had I typed-out the actual type name twice in the std::pair declaration.

Even an easier solution will be to use auto.

The `equal_range` is a member function of the multiset which is on the right of the bimap. It returns a std::pair which contains the begin and end iterators of elements in the multiset that equal the specified key, for you to iterate in the normal way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it gives only the first location. http://cpp.sh/8j74i

Comment: I should get both the keys for `100000` i,e `123456<--> 100000` and `345678<-->100000`, in the above code I get only `123456<--> 100000` that is the first location.

Comment: No, your online code example doesn't have the duplicates. You have a typo. Fix the typo, and you'll see it gives both locations.

Comment: Actually I want to make sure if the element is there. If the element is not there then the range will point to the end of the `bimap` for that I tried `if(auto itr != numbers.right.end()){....}else{...........}`, but `error: expected primary-expression before auto`

Comment: Lose the `auto`. You don't want that in the `if` statement, it's a syntax error. Just have `if (itr != numbers.right.end())`

Comment: `error: ‘itr’ was not declared in this scope`, I am trying before                 `for (auto itr = range.first; itr != range.second, ++itr){  ...}`

Comment: First the declaration. `auto itr = range.first;` Second use it (don't redeclare it) to test for end condition. `if (itr != numbers.right.end())`. Third, reuse it again (don't redeclare it) in the loop `for (itr = range.first; itr != range.second; ++itr)`